# How to separate multipart/form-data with boudary in node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, http-post, azure-functions

[Contents of the message received form the HttpPost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v7zG.png)

I have an Azure Function running on Node.js

The message that arrives has a content-type with a specified boundary.

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; 
boundary=------------------------8bb0bdeb26804014' },
```

How can I obtain the object found in the RawRequest?

```
--------------------------8bb0bdeb26804014\r\nContent-Disposition: form data; name="rawRequest"\r\n\r\n

{"slug":"submit\\/80705882093865\\/",
"q1_nombres":"first":"textbox_sample0",
"last":"textbox_sample1"},
"q3_email":"john@example.com",
"preview":"true"}\r\n
```

---

Edit1:

So far Im doing this:

```
var parts = req.headers['content-type'].split('boundary=');
var boundary = parts[1];
context.log("Boundary: "+boundary);
var splitBody = req.body.split( boundary );
context.log("RawRequest: "+splitBody[8]);
```

But I would still have to work around this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rawRequest"

{"slug":"submit\/80705882093865\/",
"q1_nombres":{"first":"textbox_sample0",
"last":"textbox_sample1"},
"q3_email":"john@example.com",
"preview":"true"} --
```

And it seems very prone to break if I just start manipulating the string even further.

Comment: You can access headers, body and other parts of the http request/response via [context object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#http-triggers-and-bindings). Is this what you are looking for? You would need to do some kind of string manipulation to parse the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method to achieve this?

```
var indexStart = splitBody.indexOf('{');
var indexEnd = splitBody.lastIndexOf('}') + 1;
var rawRequest = str.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
console.log(rawRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks! But if there is an object within the object as such is the case would it take the closing "}" of the inner object?

Comment: Worked like a Charm! Thnak you!